# Esconder formulário usando a tecla F1 C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Eu tenho formulário mais precisamente um menu de opções e queria esconder esse formulário quando eu pressionasse a tecla **F1** e mostrasse quando apertar **F1** de novo. [Tentei seguir esse tutorial do link que usa `hook keyboard`](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/19004/a-simple-c-global-low-level-keyboard-hook).

Porém, quando aperto **F1** ele esconde, mas já mostra em seguida sem ficar oculto. Para o meu caso eu não quero usar o Evento `KeyDown`, eu preciso usar esse *hook*.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
    }

    globalKeyboardHook gkh = new globalKeyboardHook();

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.F1);

        gkh.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(gkh_KeyDown);

        // gkh.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(gkh_KeyUp);
    }

    void gkh_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Show();
        e.Handled = true;            
    }

    void gkh_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void Form1_Closing(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gkh.unhook();
    }
```

Comment: `F1` é tecla padrão para `HELP`, não seria um erro utilizar assim?

Answer (score 1):

Olá, tente o seguinte:

```
private bool IsHide { get; set; } 

/*O Evento gkh_KeyUp pode ser removido, eu apenas comentei
 void gkh_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   this.Show();
   e.Handled = true;


}*/

void gkh_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(!this.IsHide)
       this.Hide();
    else
       this.Show();
    this.IsHide = !this.IsHide
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Isto está ocorrendo porquê o evento **KeyDown** é disparado quando você pressiona uma tecla, e o **KeyUp** ocorre quando você solta ela.

Então basicamente quando você pressiona ele estava escondendo, mas já mostrava ao soltar a tecla.

No código acima apenas criamos uma variável de controle para saber o que devemos fazer com o formulário.